# Singapore Index Fund(s)

Tags: etf, index-fund, singapore

What are some/is a Singapore index fund(s) on the Singapore stock exchange?  Does Singapore have sector funds on its exchange as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three ETFs that trade on the Singapore Exchange that trade the Singapore stocks:

db x-trackers MSCI Singapore IM Index UCITS ETF
https://etf.deutscheawm.com/SGP/ENG/Download/Factsheet/LU0659578842/O9A/MSCI-Singapore-IM-Index-UCITS-ETF-(DR)/Retail
(This tracks the MSCI SIngapore Investable Market Total Return Net Index)

Nikko AM Singapore STI ETF:
https://www.nikkoam.com.sg/etf/sti
(This tracks the Straits Times Index)

SPDR STI ETF
https://www.ssga.com/sg/en/institutional/etfs/funds/spdr-straits-times-index-etf-es3
(This also tracks the Straits Times Index)

You can see the entire set of ETFs that trade on SGX here:
https://www.sgx.com/securities/securities-prices?code=etfs
(although their descriptions are woefully truncated)

SGX have a screener here that allows you to find different ETFs:
https://www.sgx.com/securities/etf-screener

There are no sector ETFs.  SGX is a relatively small market.